# Get the infusionsoft tags of a post in the wp-api call

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wp-api, infusionsoft

We are using [wp-fusion](https://wpfusionplugin.com) to our wordpress. So we are using `wp-api` to fetch all the posts but now we also want to fetch the infusionsoft tags for each post.

We are making a `GET` request to fetch all the posts to the url

`{{base-url}}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`

Is it possible to add the infusionsoft tags to the `wp-api` response?

Comment: use https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/ plugin instead of wp-fusion , in json-api plugins you can create your custom function and whatever you want do functionality for them inside functions

Comment: @AnandChoudhary wp-fusion is used to communicate with infusionsoft CRM not for fetching the data from WP. I am able to fetch the posts from api but now I want to add the content of wp-fusion tags in the response.